# If I uninstall zlib2 library from my red hat linux machine, will it adversely affect my system?

Tags: linux

I am planning to uninstall and reinstall zlib on my red hat linux 6 machine. But I am not sure if that will affect my other application?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Many packages in RHEL6 includes dependancies for zlib library, I wouldn't recommend removing it from your system, instead try and reinstall the package via yum.

```
yum reinstall zlib
```

Answer (score 0):

[Zlib](https://zlib.net/) is a general-purpose compression library (zip-family). It is part of [RHEL6 distributive](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2992671) and is widely used in applications, for instance in FireFox (and other browsers). A sample list can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) in **Applications** section.

It is definitely good if not necessary to have zlib installed. There may be issues if your applications installed are not compatible with the version of zlib you want to reinstall.